# Android Studio - jump back and forth between matching braces using a single key sequence

Tags: android-studio, keymapping

I had to move from Eclipse to Android Studio for Android development. Many features are better, several are worse. In particular I miss the jump between matching braces (opening -> closing brace and v.v.) by means of a single key sequence.

I managed to find that CTRL ] takes you from the opening brace to the closing one, CTRL [ takes you from closing to opening brace. If the wrong [ or ] symbol is used when you ara already at an opening or closing brace, then the editor jumps to the next brace of that type.

Is there any key sequence which jumps between matching braces, like Eclipse does?

Comment: don't quite understand what you mean when you say matching braces. an example would help...

Comment: It's common terminology. It means find the closing brace that matches this opening one, say. So if there's a pair of {} nested quite deeply, locate the pair that go together.    See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brace_matching

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I think you want

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>}</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd>

these move to the open and close brackets.

You want a single combination to do both?

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
 + <kbd>shift</kbd>
 + <kbd>M</kbd>

[Reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/navigating-to-braces.html)

Comment: I have Ctrl [ and Ctrl ] to do that but I want one keying sequence that jumps to the matching opening or closing brace as I explained in the question.

Comment: Got it... You want a single combination to do both? Use Ctrl + shift + M

Comment: Note: ctrl+{} doesn't seem to work for parentheses, but the other shortcut does.

Comment: Is there a shortcut like ctrl+shift+m that also selects while moving the caret? I think VSCode allows this... ctrl+] to move back and forth, and ctrl+shift+} to select from one brace/parenthesis to the other. Can I do that in Android Studio?

Answer (score 24):

If this helps anyone using Android Studio on a Mac OS X machine, to jump back and forth between matching braces or parentheses, use

<kbd>control</kbd> + m

or possibly

<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + m

Comment: Do both of these commands work on Mac OS X or just `control + m` works?

Comment: On my Mac OS X (Sierra) with Android Studio 2.3.3 only `control + m`. Someone edited in the `control + shift + m` but that didn't work for me. I wasn't about to try to figure out all versions of Mac OS X and Android Studio to see if the person who added the `control + shift +m` was really correct.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Android Studio 4.2.1 and now it seems like need to use `cmd + shift + m` to move to matching bracket.
Also, this one conflicts with one of the MacOS short cut and can be modified to `ctrl + shift + m`

Answer (score -1):

**Single key solution**
You can do it as
Go to **setting->keymap** find `Move Caret To Matched Brace` add a shortcut to it.
That `shortcut` will take you to the end If you are at the opening brace **And** at the start if you are at the ending brace.
**Additional :**

**1**. For the Windows:

```
 - Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> to move to the closing bracket.

 - Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> to move to the opening bracket.

For the Mac:

 - Use  <kbd>cmd</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.
```

**2**. For the Windows:

```
  - Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>}</kbd> to move to the closing bracket with the code selection.

  - Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd> to move to the opening bracket with the code selection.

 For the Mac:

   - Use  <kbd>cmd</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.
```

Comment: No, I want a single operation which jumps to the matching brace. If you are at the opening brace, then go to the closing one. If at the closing brace then it should take you to the opening one. And I use Ubuntu.

Comment: By single operation you means ?

Comment: @NickT what is that single operation ?